# How should I deal with multiple-language questions? Are they acceptable at all?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

I often see questions tagged with [perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl), [awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/awk), and [sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sed), and perhaps some others

I could understand such tagging if all of the tagged languages were involved in the software that the OP was dealing with, but even then it would imply that "the bug is in here somewhere", and that little or no investigation has been done

But tagging like this often appears with a question that is nothing more than a request to write software that complies with a requirement, and I hope that we agree that requests for quotes don't belong here?

How should I deal with questions like this?

Comment: @Tiny: That is not a duplicate. I asked *"How should I deal with questions like this?"* and your reference doesn't help.

Comment: It sounds like you're specifically referring to questions that are some combination of too broad and/or unclear. Vote to close such questions as too broad or unclear then move on. If this does not capture the essence of your question, maybe some examples would help clarify what you're asking about. As it stands your question is somewhat unclear and overly broad.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure that the question is on-topic for the site *first*. Proper tagging can take some experience to get right, so a perfectly good question might still have wrong tags.

If it isn't: flag/vote to close, and if it's salvaged by the OP then move to the other category.

If it is: determine the *correct* tagging, and edit that in. You might also remind the OP that adding unnecessary tags does nothing to bring the attention of the people who can fix their problem. **Note that some language combinations are completely normal**, *especially* when [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) is one of them.

> I could understand such tagging if all of the tagged languages were involved in the software that the OP was dealing with, but even then it would imply that "the bug is in here somewhere", and that little or no investigation has been done

Not quite; if it's a concurrency issue, then it's sometimes difficult to tell what thread the problem is in, or even whether the problem is in server-side or client-side code. It could also be a question about *converting* between two languages: for example, a function in one language's standard library might have a different and unintuitive usage in the other language, or maybe one language lacks floating points. You should use your own judgement here; just downvote it if you don't like it.

Comment: *"flag/vote to close, and if it's salvaged by the OP then move to the other category"* Did you mean "next category"? Also, flags and votes to close give little indication to the OP about what is wrong with their question. *"Note that some language combinations are completely normal"* Yes, and I wrote in my question *"I could understand such tagging if all of the tagged languages were involved in the software that the OP was dealing with"*. Do you have any advice for answers to people who are clearly hoping for a solution of any sort at all?

Comment: @Borodin Well, you really could sum this up as "handle it like you would any other question". That's not an accident.

Comment: Did you mean *"next category"*? Your comment is unclear.

Comment: *"Well, you really could sum this up as "handle it like you would any other question""* Well maybe *you* could, but I think there is a huge difference and I am addressing those who perceive it. Telling me that you can't see the problem doesn't help anyone.